# "Dies" or "das" for introducing person

Tags: usage, pronoun

I know that in German "dies" is used not so often as "this" in English. But say, in a situation like, you're introducing your friend to another friend, and you gesture your hand toward that friend, would you say

> Dies ist ein Freund von mir.

or

> Das ist ein Freund von mir.

?

Comment: Consider *dies* as antiquated. It sounds like of a fairy-tale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both work but "das" is the default and the most common form. "Dies" sound a bit too sophisticated most of the time - if there is only one entity you could possible be meaning, that is.
"Dies" is handy when you are introducing two friend that stand at the same distance to a third friend.

> Dies ist Stefan und das ist Mark.

At least when talking about things people would go for the more colloquial "das hier" and "das hier/da" version though.

> Das hier ist mein Auto und das da das von meiner Frau.

Answer (score 2):

`Dies` is a demonstrative pronoun to the following noun. It adds a stronger meaning to the following word and makes it more important compared to the simple  `das`. Have a look to this [explanation (english/german)](http://coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/pro_07.html)

Answer (score 1):

Normal ist: Das ist ein Freund von mir. - Ich überlege gerade warum wohl "dies" in der gesprochenen Sprache eigentlich kaum gebraucht wird. Als Muttersprachler denkt man über solche Dinge eigentlich erst dann nach, wenn jemand, der Deutsch lernt, danach fragt. - Ich will nicht so tun, als ob ich das Problem genauer untersucht hätte, ich kann nur sagen, was ich vermute: "Das (hier)" mit hinweisendem Charakter wird wohl gegenüber "dies" bevorzugt, weil es in der Aussprache kürzer ist. "dies" hat ein langes i. Man würde meinen, so ein minimaler Unterschied kann doch nicht viel ausmachen. Ich meine doch. Wir kommen hier in einen Bereich, der noch nie so genau untersucht wurde, nämlich Denkgeschwindigkeit und Sprechgeschwindigkeit.
Wir denken relativ schnell, also muß die Sprechgeschwindigkeit der des Denkens einigermaßen angepaßt sein, so daß Denken und Sprechen in etwa parallel laufen. Wäre das nicht so, könnten wir wohl kaum sprechen. Wenn man sich mit Kürzungen in Sprachen befaßt, Fachbegriff Ellipsen, stellt man fest, mit Kürzungen kann man ein Lexikon füllen. "Guten Morgen" wäre eigentlich: Ich wünsche Ihnen einen guten Morgen. Für die Praxis viel zu lang. "Guten Morgen" ist beim schnellen Aneinander-Vorübergehen noch zu lang. Dann wird es so was wie "Morn", nur noch eine Silbe. Genau das Richtige, denn nach "Morn" ist der andere schon vorbei. Also ich kann mir vorstellen, dass auch bei "das" und "dies" die Kürze von "das" den Ausschlag gibt.

Comment: A word of purely **friendly** advice: Generally when someone asks a question in English, an answer in German is likely too advanced for asker.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for a simple answer:

> Das ist ein Freund von mir.

I have never ever used *dies* in this context.